# Make Image fit X and scale Y

Tags: android, xml

I have this ImageView

```
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/offer_img" />
```

I'm loading images into this ImageView from a URL and I want the image to always fit X (width of the screen) and readjust the height to keep the aspect ratio. Do I need some Java to do this or can I do it through XML alone?

Comment: and what do you want when the image.height/screen.height  > image.width/screen.width (let's say image dimensions are width=10px ; height=1000px) ? (keeping aspect ratio implies cropping the image, but how ?)

Comment: The image dimensions wont be that far out, there all around the 8:5 ratio as the website where they are uploaded to crops them to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ImageView 
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/offer_img" />
```

You will obtain what you expect only if original image ratio is around the 8:5 ratio

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with [android:scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType)

You could use the method that is the answer in this question: [Java image resize, maintain aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245220/java-image-resize-maintain-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Which would I need? There doesn't seem to be any descriptions on the dev page.

Comment: I don't know either, but I would say that 'fitXY' or 'fitStart' sounds fine

Comment: I've gone through each of one of those scale types on none do the job. Maybe because I'm loading them from the web I might have to do some Java to sort this out.

Comment: You could also set android:scaleType to fitStart and get the new resolution of the picture by your own (calculate it out) [Aspect Ratio Calculator](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/). I will edited my post to show what i mean.