# create a scaled image

Tags: java, android

I can load Images from my assets folder just fine, but now I want to scale the Image (originally 400 x 240, want it to be 800 x 480).

I can't do this with Bitmaps because of 2 reasons: (1), can't seem to create Bitmap from a file without knowing the whole path from C:\ to Assets folder, which is dumb since the whole path is gonna change depending on where app is installed; and (2), can't find a way to convert an Image to a Bitmap. And yes, i've looked up on StackOverflow how to try those/similar things, been looking them up and trying again and again for 3 days all day, no luck.

So how to scale Images? I don't understand why it's so hard to manipulate these things, and what is the difference between Bitmap and Image anyway?

Yes, I'm new to Java/Android as of 3 days ago, but I've done a lotta work in C# and other langs. PS, I know how to create and use Canvas and Paint objects. Ideally, I just need a Image scr_scale_image(Image img, int ScaleX, int Scale y) method.

thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245220/java-image-resize-maintain-aspect-ratio

Comment: Any code of you attempts and errors, while doing so?

Answer (score 0):

try imagemagick, which provides an api for java (JMagick) - http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php