# How to resize .bmp image in Java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bmp

So I am trying to resize a .bmp image using the following code:

```
void resizeSeenAreaToFitRetina(String BMPImageFileName, int newWidth, int newHeight) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bmpImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(BMPImageFileName));
    Image scaledBMPImage = bmpImage.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_FAST);
    BufferedImage scaledBufferedBMPImage = (BufferedImage) scaledBMPImage; // I know I can't do this but ImageIO.write(only_takes_BufferedImage_class_here, ...)
    ImageIO.write(scaledBufferedBMPImage, "bmp", new File("ResizedArray2DTest.bmp"));
}
```

how can I write the resized image to a file?

Comment: First of all, consider taking a look at [maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [Quality of Image after resize very low](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) for alternatives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I resize an image using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/how-can-i-resize-an-image-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope these links helps you:

[how to resize Image in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558202/how-to-resize-image-in-java)

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-image-to-file-imageio/

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged and should be made as comments

Comment: I can not write comments, I have not 50 reputation :(

Comment: Just letting you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try these links

http://www.journaldev.com/615/java-image-resize-program-using-graphics2d-example

[resizing image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895829/resizing-image-in-java)

[How can I resize an image using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/how-can-i-resize-an-image-using-java)