# How to fit BufferedImage in JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, image, swing, jeditorpane

I have a requirement where I need to create image from  HTML. I am using JEditorPane and passing the html to it. 
I have to set the height and width of JEditorPane to some default value. Since the html content is dynamic and the length of the content may vary, my images are getting cut due to larger html content or shorter.

Is there away we can get the image based on html content length?

Comment: Possibly you may scale the image, [see more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15558330/2575725).

Comment: Use the http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html to measure your height for specified width