# image resizing in java from byte [] to buffered Image

Tags: java

I am trying to scale an image   in `byte[]` form in java
but my scaled variable returns null when I set scale parameters and get  exception

```
public static byte[] resizeImage(byte[] image) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
    Image tmpImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(tmpImage);
    Image scaled = imageIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    BufferedImage buffered = ((ToolkitImage) scaled).getBufferedImage();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(buffered, "jpeg", baos);
    baos.flush();
    image = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: sorry i forgot to write the question. please check now @Arvind Kumar Avinash

Comment: Why are you using an ImageIcon, BufferedImage has getScaledInstance() method? It extends Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BufferedImage buffered = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(byte));` to create the `BufferedImage` and then check [how to resize Image in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558202/how-to-resize-image-in-java) to understand how to resize it.

Comment: What you've written is in the question.