# Java image scaling improve quality?

Tags: java, image, scaling

I am currently scaling images using the following code.

```
Image scaledImage = img.getScaledInstance( width, int height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
BufferedImage imageBuff = new BufferedImage(width, scaledImage.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = imageBuff.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, new Color(0, 0, 0), null);
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(imageBuff, "jpg", newFile);
```

Anyone have an idea of a better way of scaling an image and getting better quality results, or even any help on improving my current code to get better quality output.

Comment: You could look at the `SCALE_*` fields on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html

Comment: I think it will be helpful http://ebhor.com/high-quality-thumbnail-generation-in-java/

Comment: I've answered you question here in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967731/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-g-drawimage-method-for-resizing-images/32266733#32266733

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Affine Transorm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html)

```
public static BufferedImage getScaledImage(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) throws IOException {
    int imageWidth  = image.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = image.getHeight();

    double scaleX = (double)width/imageWidth;
    double scaleY = (double)height/imageHeight;
    AffineTransform scaleTransform = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scaleX, scaleY);
    AffineTransformOp bilinearScaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(scaleTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    return bilinearScaleOp.filter(
        image,
        new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType()));
}
```

Also try this [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Imagescale.htm) .

Also Try [java-image-scaling](https://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/) library

Comment: Got the best results using the java-image-scaling library.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at this [image scaling library](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/). It has algorithms like bicubic and Lanczos and also an unsharp filter.

Answer (score 1):

Try [avoiding Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html).