# Java problems with applying transforms to 3 graphics2d images based on JButton

Tags: java, swing, affinetransform

I'm still relatively new to Java. Also, this is a school project.

Goal: When run, the program is SUPPOSED TO create and display 3 ea. 25x25 images. Then, whenever a button is pushed, various transforms are to be applied to each of the images. My problem is that none of the transforms are being applied.

I have 3 classes: a drawing area, a GUI builder, and a main run class.
So far the GUI is coming up,the initial images are displayed, and the listeners for buttons are good to go. When the buttons are pushed, the appropriate messages appear but nothing changes with my images.

Here's the GUI builder:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

//@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Project1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 
public static JButton nextTransformBtn;
public static JButton closeBtn;
//public static JLabel label;
public static JFrame window;
public static JPanel topPanel;
public static DrawArea panel;
public static Border blackLine;
private int frameNumber;  // A counter that increases by one in each frame.
private long elapsedTimeMillis;  // The time, in milliseconds, since the animation started.
private float pixelSize;  // This is the measure of a pixel in the coordinate system
                          // set up by calling the applyWindowToViewportTransformation method.  It can be used
                          // for setting line widths, for example.
public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;
public static int count ;
int num ;
//public static final String TITLE = " Project 1";


/** constructor
 * @param args 
 */
public Project1() throws ParseException { 
    /**
     * Set properties of Project1 JFrame
     */
    super("Project 1");
    setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setBackground( Color.lightGray );
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    /**
     * Creates black line for border
     */        
    blackLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);

    /**
     * Create a JPanel to display Graphics
     */  
    panel = new DrawArea();
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel.setBorder(blackLine);

    /**
     * Create components for topPanel
     */     
    //label = new JLabel("    Project 1 ");
    nextTransformBtn = new JButton("Next transform");
    closeBtn= new JButton("Exit Program");

    /**
     * Create a topPanel for text box and
     * set its properties
     */     
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
    topPanel.setLayout(layout);
    topPanel.setBorder(blackLine);
    //topPanel.add(label);
    topPanel.add(nextTransformBtn);
    topPanel.add(closeBtn);

    /**
     * Add topPanel and panel to JFrame
     */ 
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    /**
     * Create ActionListeners for buttons
     */         
    closeBtn.addActionListener(e-> System.exit(0));
    nextTransformBtn.addActionListener(e-> {
        System.out.print (count + " - ");
        panel.doTransform(count);
        panel.redrawComponent();
        count++;
        if(count == 6) count = 0;
    });

}// end constructor method

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

And here's the drawing area:

```
public class DrawArea extends JPanel{
BufferedImage boxImage;      
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
public Graphics2D g2;
public DrawArea(){
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setSize(800,600);
}

public void doTransform(int count){
    switch(count){
        case 0:
            at.translate(-5, 0);
            System.out.println("Translate images -5 in X direction.");
            break;
        case 1:
            at.translate(0,7);
            System.out.println("Translate images 7 in Y direction.");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Rotates images 45 degrees counter clockwise.");
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
            break;
        case 3:
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(-90));
            System.out.println("Rotates images 90 degrees clockwise.");
            break;
        case 4:
            at.scale(2, 0);
            System.out.println("Scales images 2 times for X component.");
            break;
        case 5:
            at.scale(0, 0.5);
            System.out.println("Scales images 0.5 times for Y component.");
            break;
    }
    g2.setTransform(at);
}
public void redrawComponent(){
    repaint();
}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()); // From the old graphics API!
    setPixelSize(g2, -100, 100, -100, 100, true);
    /* 
     * Create images and store in 2d array
     */
    int blk = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
    int boxData[][]= newint[25][25];
    for(int x = 0 ; x<25 ; x++){
        for(int y = 0 ; y<25 ; y++){
            if( x==0 || y==0 || x == 24 || y == 24){
                boxData[x][y] = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
            } else if (x>y){
                boxData[x][y] = Color.red.getRGB();
            } else if (x<y){
                boxData[x][y] = Color.blue.getRGB();
            }
        }
    }
    boxImage = new BufferedImage(25, 25 ,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);                
    //box
    for (int x = 0 ; x<25 ; x++){
        for(int y = 0 ; y<25 ; y++){
            boxImage.setRGB(x,y,boxData[x][y]);
        }
    }
    g2.drawImage(boxImage, -13, -40, this);        

    AffineTransform saveXform = g2.getTransform();
    AffineTransform toCenterAt = new AffineTransform();
    toCenterAt.concatenate(at);
    g2.transform(toCenterAt);
    g2.setTransform(saveXform);
}
private void setPixelSize(Graphics2D g2,
        double left, double right, double bottom, double top, 
        boolean preserveAspect) {
    int width = getWidth();   // The width of this drawing area, in pixels.
    int height = getHeight(); // The height of this drawing area, in pixels.
    if (preserveAspect) {
        // Adjust the limits to match the aspect ratio of the drawing area.
        double displayAspect = Math.abs((double)height / width);
        double requestedAspect = Math.abs(( bottom-top ) / ( right-left ));
        if (displayAspect > requestedAspect) {
            // Expand the viewport vertically.
            double excess = (bottom-top) * (displayAspect/requestedAspect - 1);
            bottom += excess/2;
            top -= excess/2;
        }
        else if (displayAspect < requestedAspect) {
            // Expand the viewport vertically.
            double excess = (right-left) * (requestedAspect/displayAspect - 1);
            right += excess/2;
            left -= excess/2;
        }
    }
    g2.scale( width / (right-left), height / (bottom-top) );
    g2.translate( -left, -top );
    double pixelWidth = Math.abs(( right - left ) / width);
    double pixelHeight = Math.abs(( bottom - top ) / height);
    pixelSize = (float)Math.max(pixelWidth,pixelHeight);
}// end setPixelSize method

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

And now my main class...

```
import java.text.ParseException;


public class runProject1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{

    final Project1 panel = new Project1();
    panel.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome! Where is your main method? How does it look like?

Comment: Pro-tip: once you've applied block formatting to code posted here, you don't also need backticks - they are just for small pieces of inline code.

Comment: Edit your original post and add the 3rd class ... the one containing your main method.

Comment: Don't save a reference to `Graphics`, this a really bad idea fraught with no end of issues.  Instead, update you transformation as you need, call `repaint` and update the transformation of the supplied `Graphics` context.  Make sure you also call `super.paintComponent` first.  Also best to `create` and `dispose` of the `Graphics` context first as it's a shared resource and strange things will happen if your change the transform and don't undo it

Comment: @Noureddine Ouertani, I opted to leave it out due to it's size, but now see that I should have thrown it in for full disclosure. ... its in now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problems start here:

```
public Graphics2D g2;
```

There is no reason to maintain a reference to the system `Graphics` context, let alone make it `public`.  The `Graphics` is controlled by the paint system and you will be given a instance to paint to when the system needs you to update the component.

So, instead, update your transform as you need and call `repaint` on the component, apply the transform to the `Graphics` context passed to the `paintComponent` method

```
public class DrawArea extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage boxImage;
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

    public DrawArea() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setSize(800, 600);
    }

    public void doTransform(int count) {
        at = new AffineTransform();
        switch (count) {
            case 0:
                at.translate(-5, 0);
                System.out.println("Translate images -5 in X direction.");
                break;
            case 1:
                at.translate(0, 7);
                System.out.println("Translate images 7 in Y direction.");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Rotates images 45 degrees counter clockwise.");
                at.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
                break;
            case 3:
                at.rotate(Math.toRadians(-90));
                System.out.println("Rotates images 90 degrees clockwise.");
                break;
            case 4:
                at.scale(2, 0);
                System.out.println("Scales images 2 times for X component.");
                break;
            case 5:
                at.scale(0, 0.5);
                System.out.println("Scales images 0.5 times for Y component.");
                break;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void redrawComponent() {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Let the API fill the background       
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        AffineTransform toCenterAt = new AffineTransform();
        // This centers the transform in the available space
        toCenterAt.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        toCenterAt.concatenate(at);
        g2.transform(toCenterAt);

        /*
        Create images and store in 2d array
         */
        int blk = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
        int boxData[][] = new int[25][25];
        for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 25; y++) {
                if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == 24 || y == 24) {
                    boxData[x][y] = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
                } else if (x > y) {
                    boxData[x][y] = Color.red.getRGB();
                } else if (x < y) {
                    boxData[x][y] = Color.blue.getRGB();
                }
            }
        }
        boxImage = new BufferedImage(25, 25, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        //box
        for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 25; y++) {
                boxImage.setRGB(x, y, boxData[x][y]);
            }
        }
        g2.drawImage(boxImage, -13, -40, this);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

This code resets the transform each time, remember transformations are cumulative

You may also like to have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396302/how-to-scale-image-using-getscaledinstance/18396317#18396317) for some more ideas

I might also point out the overuse of `static` is very dangerous and could cause no end of issues if you're not careful. `static` is not a means for cross object communication and you should use it sparingly

Answer (score 0):

Here try this.  It's transforming now.  I changed a few things, so go back and see what I changed to see what was wrong in the first place.  Also moved the repaint into the doTransform method.

```
public class DrawArea extends JPanel{
    float pixelSize;
    BufferedImage boxImage;      
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    public DrawArea(){
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setSize(800,600);
    }

public void doTransform(int count){
    switch(count){
    case 0:
        at.translate(-5, 0);
        System.out.println("Translate images -5 in X direction.");
        break;
    case 1:
        at.translate(0,7);
        System.out.println("Translate images 7 in Y direction.");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Rotates images 45 degrees counter clockwise.");
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
        break;
    case 3:
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(-90));
        System.out.println("Rotates images 90 degrees clockwise.");
        break;
    case 4:
        at.scale(2, 0);
        System.out.println("Scales images 2 times for X component.");
        break;
    case 5:
        at.scale(0, 0.5);
        System.out.println("Scales images 0.5 times for Y component.");
        break;
    }
    repaint();

}
public void redrawComponent(){
    repaint();
}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()); // From the old graphics API!
    setPixelSize(g2, -100, 100, -100, 100, true);
    /* 
     * Create images and store in 2d array
     */
    int blk = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
    int boxData[][]= new int[25][25];
    for(int x = 0 ; x<25 ; x++){
        for(int y = 0 ; y<25 ; y++){
            if( x==0 || y==0 || x == 24 || y == 24){
                boxData[x][y] = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
            } else if (x>y){
                boxData[x][y] = Color.red.getRGB();
            } else if (x<y){
                boxData[x][y] = Color.blue.getRGB();
            }
        }
    }
    boxImage = new BufferedImage(25, 25 ,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);                
    //box
    for (int x = 0 ; x<25 ; x++){
        for(int y = 0 ; y<25 ; y++){
            boxImage.setRGB(x,y,boxData[x][y]);
        }
    }


    AffineTransform saveXform = g2.getTransform();
    AffineTransform toCenterAt = new AffineTransform();
    toCenterAt.concatenate(at);
    g2.transform(toCenterAt);
    g2.setTransform(saveXform);

    g2.setTransform(at);
    g2.drawImage(boxImage, 100, 100, this);

}
private void setPixelSize(Graphics2D g2,
        double left, double right, double bottom, double top, 
        boolean preserveAspect) {
    int width = getWidth();   // The width of this drawing area, in pixels.
    int height = getHeight(); // The height of this drawing area, in pixels.
    if (preserveAspect) {
        // Adjust the limits to match the aspect ratio of the drawing area.
        double displayAspect = Math.abs((double)height / width);
        double requestedAspect = Math.abs(( bottom-top ) / ( right-left ));
        if (displayAspect > requestedAspect) {
            // Expand the viewport vertically.
            double excess = (bottom-top) * (displayAspect/requestedAspect - 1);
            bottom += excess/2;
            top -= excess/2;
        }
        else if (displayAspect < requestedAspect) {
            // Expand the viewport vertically.
            double excess = (right-left) * (requestedAspect/displayAspect - 1);
            right += excess/2;
            left -= excess/2;
        }
    }
    g2.scale( width / (right-left), height / (bottom-top) );
    g2.translate( -left, -top );
    double pixelWidth = Math.abs(( right - left ) / width);
    double pixelHeight = Math.abs(( bottom - top ) / height);
    pixelSize = (float)Math.max(pixelWidth,pixelHeight);
}// end setPixelSize method

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}