# How to get scaled instance of a bufferedImage

Tags: java, scale, bufferedimage, toolkit

I wanted to get scaled instance of a buffered image and I did:

```
public void analyzePosition(BufferedImage img, int x, int y){   
     img =  (BufferedImage) img.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
....
}
```

but I do get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage
    at ImagePanel.analyzePosition(ImagePanel.java:43)
```

I wanted then to cast to `ToolkitImage` then use the method `getBufferedImage` I read about in other articles. The problem is there is no class such as `sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage` I cannot cast to it because Eclipse does not even see this class. I use `Java 1.7` and `jre1.7`.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a new image, a BufferedImage with the TookitImage.

```
Image toolkitImage = img.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), 
      Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
int width = toolkitImage.getWidth(null);
int height = toolkitImage.getHeight(null);

// width and height are of the toolkit image
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, 
      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(toolkitImage, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();

// now use your new BufferedImage
```

Answer (score 6):

`BufferedImage#getScaledInstance` is actually inherited from `java.awt.Image` and only guarantees that it will return an `Image` so I would say it's not a good idea to try and assume the underlying return type in this case.

`getScaledInstance` is, also, not normally the fastest or best quality method

To scale a `BufferedImage` itself, you have a number of different options, but most simply take the original and repaint it to another image, applying some kind of scaling in process.

For example:

- [Scale the ImageIcon automatically to label size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)
- [Position Image in any Screen Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847816/position-image-in-any-screen-resolution/17848635#17848635)
- [how to make image stretchable in swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053310/how-to-make-image-stretchable-in-swing/18054307#18054307)

For more details about `getScaledInstance`, have a read of [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611)