# BufferedImage.getScaledInstance() not resizing image

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'm having some problems understanding this line of code:

```
bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(100, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

I use it to resize an image with following numbers. Width: 3264px, height: 2448px, horizontal & vertical resolution: 150dpi, size: 2.72MB.

Then I save the bufferedImage into a File using

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputFile);
```

It resulted in a picture with the following numbers: Same width & height (3264x2448), horizontal & vertical resolution: 96dpi, size: 674KB.

Isn't the picture suppose to be `100px` in width, and whatever height to maintain aspect ratio (according to Javadoc)? And why would the result pic have the same width & height, but different hor&ver resolution, and size? Am I missing something, cause it seems like no matter what value of width & height, the result pic is always the same as described above.

I've also read that I should draw the resized `BufferedImage` into a `Graphics2D`, and save the `Graphics2D` into file. Is that the proper way to do it, rather than saving the `BufferedImage` straight into file?

The image I'm using is [here](http://rubiksaigon.com/postingagent/images/20161206_231336.jpg)

Comment: Check its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)), it says "If either width or height is a negative number then a value is substituted to maintain the aspect ratio of the original image dimensions". I guess it fails to maintain the same aspect ratio with 1px width, and resets to original dimensions.

Comment: Aspect ratio is maintained, however, dimension should not be. In my case, dimension is also maintained, while I'm trying to resize it.

Comment: You are getting the response of the `.getScaledInstance()` right? It does not modify the `bufferedImage`, but returns the scaled image instance. If not, you might be writing the non-scaled image, and due to usage of `"jpg"` you might get the resolution change in the output image.

Comment: Oh no I totally did not. I thought it scales it directly. Guess that's why u have to use Graphics2D, to work with the returned Image. I'll try it & update this thread. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need `Graphics2D`. `getScaledInstance()` returns an `Image` object, just try to get its response, and `write()` on that object. `Image scaledImage = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(100, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);` and `ImageIO.write(scaledImage, "jpg", outputFile);`

Comment: You can't write an `Image` object though, `ImageIO.write()` requires `RenderedImage`

Comment: You are right, sorry, use the following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19506998/3641067), to get `BufferedImage` from the response of `getScaledInstance()`, and `write()` that!

Comment: It works, only thing is the quality is low. I'm looking at ways to increase the quality. And yeah post an answer so I can up-vote you (not sure if I can due to low reputation, but I'll try). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the response of the `.getScaledInstance()`. It does not modify the `bufferedImage`, but returns the scaled image instance. Due to the usage of "jpg" you might get the resolution change in the output image.

So you'd have to do the following;

```
Image scaledImage = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(100, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
// map Image to BufferedImage
ImageIO.write(scaledBufferedImage, "jpg", outputFile);
```

To create a `BufferedImage` from the scaled `Image`, use the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506927/how-to-get-scaled-instance-of-a-bufferedimage/19506998#19506998).