# set size of image after retrieving from json

Tags: java, json, swing, user-interface

I want to set the size of image get through json service. ???

Here is my code

```
public void getImage(){
 try {

        URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=good%20idea%20good%20idea%20water%20jug%20water%20jug%20thirsty%20crow%20thirsty%20crow%20long%20time%20long%20time%20jug%20jug");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        String imageUrl = json.getJSONObject("responseData").getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("url");

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageUrl));

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(image);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("", img, JLabel.CENTER);

        jPanel1.add( label, BorderLayout.CENTER );


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Failure", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
}
```

I am showing the image in a jPanel.I want to set the size of image so it must be smaller than panel size. How could I achieve this ????

Comment: [maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [Quality of Image after resize very low](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Comment: You have a catch 22 problem, the size of the panel is normally determined by the size of the contents (the image in this case), maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053310/how-to-make-image-stretchable-in-swing/18054307#18054307) might help.  It's a `JPanel` which can paint the image, but which scales the image so that it will "fit" within it

Comment: I have tried the code [this]<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053310/how-to-make-image-stretchable-in-swing/18054307#18054307> I don't need the image to be stretchable so i **updated / altered** my code according to my need  but could not find this helpful. This is a good work but i don't find this helpful. So is there any **method** that altered size of images  by directly **specifying width, height** to json image.

Comment: `BufferedImage#getScaledInstance` - but then I'd have to point you to [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/article/2007/03/30/perils-imagegetscaledinstance). You could also have a look at [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/), but as I said, you may have a catch 22 problem, in the fact that the size of the panel is normally dictated by the size of it's content (the `JLabel` and image).  The first link I posted also scales an image while maintaining it's aspect ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the quality of the result, you could use [`Image#getScaledInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)), but you should have a read of [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/article/2007/03/30/perils-imagegetscaledinstance) of first

```
Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(jPanel1.getWidth(), jPanel1.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

But this won't maintain the aspect ratio of the image, to do that, you'd have to decide which dimension is more important

```
int width = jPanel1.getWidth();
int height = jPanel1.getHeight();
if (width < height) {
    height = -1;
} else {
    width = -1;
}
Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Have a look at [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) for more details

Now, if you do care about the quality of the resulting image, then you need to use a different scaling approach, you could use something like a divide and conqure approach, as demonstrated in [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) or use a 3rd party library, like [ImgSclr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)

Now, you next problem is, the size of a component is generally calculated based on the needs of it's children.  In this case, that means that `jPanel1` may want to use the size of the `JLabel` to determine how large it should be.  Equally, the `JLabel` will use the size of the image to determine how large it should be.  Which puts you in a catch 22 problem.

You could use a `JScrollPane` which will allow the image to occupy a large area then is available or you will need a dynamic panel which can resize the image automatically based on the available space, but you would still need to make a determination of what the "default" or "preferred" size should be

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);
```

Comment: It's that an Android API?

Comment: `ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(image)` I get image from JSON it is of type ImageIcon. The above code image is of type  **Bitmap** not working

Comment: No Its not an Android API. It is Google API AJAX Service. It will call Image results in JSON fromat .Check out This . Provide image url in JSON Data /URL body<http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/>

Comment: `BitMap` is not a standard class of the Java API, is part of a Google library?  I've only seen it in the Android API

Comment: ok. coming back to my question. I have get image from google ajax api in JSON format How do I set the width and height of that image?