# User Scalable java component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Let's say I have a JTree inside a JFrame.

Is it possible to allow the user to scale the widths of the panel when the user is using it, just like users are allowed to scale the panels/pallettes in IDEs, or other applications?

One close possibility that I found was adding JTree inside a InternalFrame and make the InternalFrame resizable using setResizable(true). This does show the cursors that allows you to resize, but upon running the application, it does not resize as desired.

Source code (created using NetBeans):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package somePackage;

/**
 *
 * @author somebody
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jDesktopPane1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        jInternalFrame2 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTree1 = new javax.swing.JTree();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jInternalFrame2.setResizable(true);
        jInternalFrame2.setVisible(true);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTree1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame2.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame2Layout);
        jInternalFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        jInternalFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 430, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(340, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jDesktopPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(59, 59, 59))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame2)
                .addGap(363, 363, 363)
                .addComponent(jDesktopPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTree jTree1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: In theory yes, in practice it's a lot more complicated

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053310/how-to-make-image-stretchable-in-swing/18054307#18054307)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you for the link. 
It sad that we don't have a decorator in swing something like a scrollpane, that would allow scaling its contents. Thank you again.

Comment: You mean like `JInternalFrame`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Yeah, but as said above, JInternalFrame does not allow me to resize. It does show the resize cursors, but does not resize when I drag them.

Comment: Then you're using it wrong, have a look at [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for more details