# How to fit an image size to ImageIcon and JLabel size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, imageicon

My project is Open an image and Save it again, I use ImageIcon,JLabel and JPanel to display it (I used ImageIcon and JPanel, but It didn't work, ImageIcon could not add to JPanel). when I open it, It always display the image but not full size to JFrame.
this code I write in class OpenImage extends JFrame

```
public class Draw_JPanel extends JFrame{
       Load_image panel_im = new Load_image();
public void OpenImage()
{   
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String name = file.getName();
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageic = new ImageIcon(image);
        height1 = imageic.getIconHeight();
        width1 = imageic.getIconWidth();
         picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
         panel_im.add(picLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    this.pack();

}
```

and the code of Load_image class

```
public class Load_image extends JPanel{
public Load_image()
{   
    this.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
}
```

Sorry but I can't upload image

Comment: you see full size of your image? or your try to resize your image to fill all `JFrame` area?

Comment: I try to resize my image size to JFrame

Comment: I think your image has fixed size, because of it your Label can't resize it, if you want to resize image try to read [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967731/java-scale-image-best-practice) and [that](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/) or find somthing else

Comment: my projectis display and save it against, but if I resize image to JFrame, when I save it, its size will be change. how can I pack an imageIcon to JLabel and then pack to JPanel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple example for you. It draws image and resizes it with help of [imgscalr library](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/#download). Also you can save image. Try it, I think it helps you.

```
public class Example extends JPanel{

    private static BufferedImage scaledImg;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        f.add(e,c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.gridx = 1;
        JButton b = new JButton("save");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                File outputfile = new File("c:\\image.png");
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(scaledImg, "png", outputfile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        f.add(b,c);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
        super.paintComponent(arg0);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) arg0;
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read( Example.class.getResource("/res/3_disc.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scaledImg = Scalr.resize(img,getSize().height,getSize().width,new BufferedImageOp[]{});
        g.drawImage (scaledImg, null, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

here `"/res/3_disc.png"` is image in my project

`"c:\\image.png"` output for image

Comment: I'm trying with your code, but what is Scalr Object? I can't find anywhere you declare it

Comment: `Scalr` it's class from library, I point it the text. Download it and add to classpath

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code, I add setBounds() method and setLayout() method, here my code after fixed:

```
setLayout(null);
        imageic = new ImageIcon(image);
        height1 = imageic.getIconHeight();
        width1 = imageic.getIconWidth();
        picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        picLabel.setSize(width1, height1);
        picLabel.setBounds(0, 0, width1, height1);
        panel_im.setSize(width1, height1);
        panel_im.setBounds(-5, -5, width1, height1);
        panel_im.add(picLabel);
        this.pack();
```

tks for all