# What is the fastest way to modify an image file in java

Tags: java, image

What is the fastest way to modify an image file (apply filters, change resolution, etc..) in java.

I tried to open a file with `ImageIO` and modify with `java.awt.image`

```
ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
op.filter(bufferedImage, bufferedImage);
```

It took a lot of time, do you have any faster method to do it?

Comment: "to modify" is probably too broad. I wrote a [somewhat extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32278737/3182664) a while ago where I (only!) investigated the performance for **scaling** an image, and this already has many degrees of freedom, and the performance varies wildly with them...

Comment: not really "in java", but quite fast... https://imagemagick.org/script/api.php

Comment: Do you consider a SVG file an image file?