# Obtain the DPI from a image file (PSD, JPG and PNG) using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to obtain the standard dpi values from images (the one depicted in the image attached)

I tried pillow method .get('dpi') and it fgives me no results

I tried to obtain the properties and that it the output i got:

```
from PIL import Image

image_file = Image.open(jpg)

image_file.info

>>>> [enter image description here][1]{'adobe': 100, 'adobe_transform': 100}
```

A user can see the properties form the image and check the dpi, how can i extract it from Python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get image dpi for tif files using Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050345/get-image-dpi-for-tif-files-using-pillow)

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I tried to obtain by creating an Image object but is gives me KeyError all the time i try to access. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: maybe the image file does not have the dpi EXIF information, can you share a link to the image you are trying to check?