How to draw bounding boxes around sections in the result from azure document intelligence?
I am using Azure Document Intelligence to analyse document. The polygon I am receiving looks like this,
[2.5735, 4.6218, 2.6712, 4.6218, 2.6712, 4.7218, 2.5735, 4.7218]

If I draw this on the image using cv2, there are outside the document. I can see the unit for Azure is inch. I think, I need to translate these numbers using the document/page shape. But could not figure out how to?
Any help?

You need to convert this polygon from inches to pixels and based on your document dpi you have to draw the lines.
You below code.
import cv2
import numpy as np

polygon_in_inches = [2.5735, 4.6218, 2.6712, 4.6218, 2.6712, 4.7218, 2.5735, 4.7218]

dpi = 200

polygon_in_pixels = [[int(x * dpi), int(y * dpi)] for x, y in zip(polygon_in_inches[::2], polygon_in_inches[1::2])]
polygon_in_pixelsd = np.array([polygon_in_pixels], np.int32).reshape((-1, 1, 2))

image = cv2.imread('tmp.png')
cv2.polylines(image, [polygon_in_pixelsd], isClosed=True, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
cv2.imwrite('output_image.png', image)

Here, i used dpi value 200.
Output:

If you observe, a small region is created in the image.

Hi @JayashankarGS
Thanks a million for your response. However, the question is how do I get dpi? I have a pdf file, my-pdf.pdf that has 20 pages. Say page 10 is your tmp.png ( I have jpg). Now, I have polygon from Microsoft Azure Document Intelligence that are based on the pdf file. And I split the pdf file into jpg images. Then, from where I can get the dpi? Is there a smart way or Microsoft Azure way?

Actually when you open the image and in details you will find. But in programming way get the metadata. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050345/get-image-dpi-for-tif-files-using-pillow
