# Android: Image Noise Removal

Tags: java, android

As stated in the documentation on improving the accuracy of OCR 
https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ImproveQuality#Noise
Noise reduction on a bitmap is very important so,

I have this code that I referenced from here.

[image processing to improve tesseract OCR accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480013/image-processing-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-accuracy)

And I have modified and debugged the code to look something like this:

```
public Bitmap RemoveNoise(Bitmap bmap)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bmap.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmap.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            int pixel = bmap.getPixel(x, y);
            if (pixel.R < 162 && pixel.G < 162 && pixel.B < 162)
                bmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    for (int  x = 0; x < bmap.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmap.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            int pixel = bmap.getPixel(x, y);
            if (pixel.R > 162 && pixel.G > 162 && pixel.B > 162)
                bmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    return bmap;
}
```

My challenge is that after debugging the code I have error on pixel.R, pixel.G and pixel.B and that is where I am hooked up right now.
Also, could this be a better algorithm or approach of removing noise from an image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code

```
public Bitmap RemoveNoise(Bitmap bmap) {
    for (int x = 0; x < bmap.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmap.getHeight(); y++) {
            int pixel = bmap.getPixel(x, y);
            int R = Color.red(pixel);
            int G = Color.green(pixel);
            int B = Color.blue(pixel);
            if (R < 162 && G < 162 && B < 162)
                bmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
    for (int  x = 0; x < bmap.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmap.getHeight(); y++) {
            int pixel = bmap.getPixel(x, y);
            int R = Color.red(pixel);
            int G = Color.green(pixel);
            int B = Color.blue(pixel);
            if (R > 162 && G > 162 && B > 162)
                bmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return bmap;
}
```