# Image processing using opencv before doing OCR on an image using tesseract

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I've been trying to train tesseract engine to ocr images that have numbers written using the seven digital font.

[image: Seven digital font]

And, after searching, it turned out that tesseract won't ocr a segmented font unless the segments are somehow connected.

So, I used erosion, which is an opencv function, on the images to connect the segments.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/eroding_dilating.htm

And, after that, I used thresholding to convert the image to binary before handing the image to tesseract (This step is redundant because tesseract internally does image binarization).
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html

My main problem is that the numbers are written in black on a dark green background.
Here are the results

Original image:

[image: Original Image to be ocred]

Method 1:
After Erosion and binarization (I tried various threshold max values)
[image: Image after binarization]

Method 2:
I tried to use k-means or c-means algorithms but the results were no much better.

Method 3:
I also tried adaptive Gaussian thresholding
[image: Adaptive Gaussian threshold]

Method 4:
Adaptive Mean
[image: Just adaptive mean]

Method 5:
Handing the original image to tesseract without any image processing and outputting the result image (Tesseract uses leptonica to do image processing internally).
[image: Tesseract image processing]

I also tried various samples instead of this one and tried Gimp to enhance the images using the steps in [Gimp image processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473095/image-to-text-recognition-using-tesseract-ocr-is-better-when-image-is-preprocess), but nothing is working for me.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you get better input images? i.e. less shiny/dark spots across the image.. similar brightnesses, because this is probably you're main enemy, hence on the last image the dark splodge on the left and the light on the right

Comment: Yes, I know, but I can't control the conditions when the images are taken, so I can't assume that I will have perfect shots. I've had some good results on some samples, but the majority of the samples can't be ocred, so I thought that maybe there is some green filter to apply, or something that I can do. Thank you @TheLethalCoder

Comment: If the images are that poor you can always threshold at multiple values, get the ocr data then using the positional information of the characters add up the results of each value, extra work but could be a decent workaround

Comment: I will try your suggestion and see what I can get.

Comment: @AbdulmajeedAl-Kattan did you solve it?