# How to get region of interest in images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning

[image: Example]

I need to train R-CNN on my dataset. Above Image is an example in which first column contain path to that image and second column contain coordinates of bounded box(ROI). **How to get those coordinates in matlab.** As my dataset is large so how those coordinates can be extracted by pointing manually.

for example if i am training R-CNN foe stop signs then second column contain coordinates of bounded box containing stop sign in whole image.

Comment: Load the image, and then access it using  matrix indexing.

Comment: You can extract the text data back to excel sheet format using OCR, i have already answered this similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46806306/5545458

Comment: It is thoroughly unclear what you want to do. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know which version of MATLAB you are running, but I'm assuming it is fairly new (R2017a and later). Also, by 'how to get the coordinates', I assume you mean 'how to determine' or 'how to assign' the coordinates.

I believe what you need to do is to use one of the image labeling Apps called

```
imageLabeler
```

to annotate rectangles in your training images. You either do this manually if that's amenable, or you need to use automation algorithms if you already have a detector that does something similar. See this page for more details:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/create-and-import-an-automation-algorithm-for-ground-truth-labeling.html

Once you have the results of labeling stored in a `groundTruth` object, you would need to use something like `objectDetectorTrainingData` to create the table you are looking for.

See https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-an-object-detector-from-ground-truth-data.html for more details.