# How to detect simple text with Tesseract ORC?

Tags: tesseract, linux-mint, leptonica

I'm trying to convert simple image with numbers to text using https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract. I compiled latest version from github with Leptonica and other libs required for image process.

My image looks like this:
[image]

I'm trying to convert it like this: `/usr/local/bin/tesseract '/home/var/img2text/phone.png'  out` but instead of numbers something like `3m mam`. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The image is small and the quality of it is a little low, try the following:

1- Change its DPI to 300

2- Resize the image 2x and apply Resample interpolation.

3- Make sure it is a B/W image.

Here are some useful links:

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ImproveQuality

[image processing to improve tesseract OCR accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480013/image-processing-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-accuracy)