# What does the Tesseract OCR library require of an image to be able to accurately extract text?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using the Tesseract library to extract text from images. The language is Vietnamese. I have two images. The first one is from a website. The second is a screenshot taken from the Wordpad program. They are shown in links below:

### 1

[image]

### 2

[image]

The first one has 95% accuracy.

> Bán căn hộ tầng 5 khu tập thể Thành công Bắc, DT 28m2, gần chợ ThànhCông, 
>   số
>   đỏ, chính chủ, giá 800 triệu.LH:A.Châu, 0979622551,0905685336

The second image is much larger but the accuracy is just about 60%.

> Bặn căn hộ tầng ậ khu tập thể Ỉhành gông
>   Băc. llĩ 28 m2. gân chợ ĩllành Bông. sũ Ilỏ.
>   chính l:lIlì. giá 800 lriệu. l.ll: A.BhâU,
>   0979622551, 0905685336

What about the second image do I have to fix to get as accurate text as the first one?

Comment: Try re-training Tesseract for the second font.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @user898678 in [image processing to improve tesseract OCR accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480013/image-processing-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-accuracy) ,
the following operations can improve OCR's accuracy :

- fix DPI (if needed) 300 DPI is minimum
- fix text size (e.g. 12 pt should be ok)
- try to fix text lines (deskew and dewarp text)
- try to fix illumination of image (e.g. no dark part of image
  binarize and de-noise image

Comment: the font text size in the  second image is larger than 12pt. The words in the images are in the same straight line. Also, i don't see any dark part of the image. I am thinking about ways to improve the boldness level of the text in the second image. That might fix the problem but i don't know how