# How can I be Android tesseract Increasing recognition?

Tags: android, ocr, tess-two

I am developing an Android OCR.
Using tess-two in the Android made the OCR.
I have downloaded the 'traineddata'(tess-two) file in from [here](https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR).

I wanted to increase the recognition performance of 'traineddata' files.
But I found code only for iphone or C++ language.
Please advise me how to improve the Android 'traineddata' recognition probability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [image processing to improve tesseract OCR accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480013/image-processing-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-accuracy)

Comment: thank you ~ X0 kkk

Comment: thanks I will accept your word

Answer (score 0):

For more accurate recognition can you please go through google api. It provide a better character recognition