# Determining text in a pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am analyzing a PDF document to try to determine a date in it (see image).
I have two java methods at my disposal:

```
 PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fil);
```

opens the PDF file into a PDDocument object., and

```
 String strip = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
```

gets all the text from the pdf file into a string.  Here is what I am trying to read (June 30, 2019)]

[image]

Now here it is as text:

```
This Agreement, which is effective as of\efip2\                               (the "Effective Date")
```

So would I be correct in assuming that \efip2\ is an image?  There is probably no way to determine a date from that image, right?  Or is it not an image but some kind of include?  Any idea how to get it?

Comment: If this is an image you actually can analyze it using [OpenCV for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170714/reading-text-from-image-using-tesseract-and-opencv-java)

Comment: If it is an image, you might be able to use OCR.

Comment: From the screenshot alone it is not clear. Please share the PDF.