# Extract text from light text on withe background image

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have an image like the following:

[image: Image to be processed]

and I would want to extract the text from it, that should be `ws35`, I've tried with **pytesseract** library using the method :

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(path))
```

but it returns nothing... Am I doing something wrong? How can I get back the text using the OCR ?  Do I need to apply some filter on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @SilverMonkey's suggestion: Gaussian blur followed by Otsu thresholding.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following approach:

- [Binarize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)) the image with a method of your choice (Thresholding with 127 seems to be sufficient in this case)
- Use a [minimum filter](https://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm/minimum-maximum-median-filters.htm#Morphological) to connect the lose dots to form characters. Thereby, a filter with r=4 seems to work quite good: [image: Image after application of minimum filter]
- If necessary the result can be further improved via application of a [median blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) (r=4): [image]

Because i personally do not use tesseract i am not able to try this picture, but online ocr tools seem to be able to identify the sequence correctly (especially if you use the blurred version).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this picture is low quality and very noisy!
even proffesional and enterprisal programs are struggling with this

you have most likely seen a capatcha before and the reason for those is because its sent back to a database with your answer and the image and then used to train computers to read images like these.

> short answer is: pytesseract cant read the text inside this image and most likely no module or proffesional programs can read it either.

Answer (score 0):

You may need apply some image processing/enhancement on it. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10034214/9528291) post read suggestions and try to apply.