# Tesseract found no text in image with dotted background

Tags: c#, tesseract

I want to read the amount from an image with a dotted background.
 [image]

The Tesseract engine doesn't find anything.

How can I train him to identifiy the amount.

Comment: Can you subtract the background to help Tesseract out, or use an anti-noise algorithm to remove dots below a certain size (this may make decimal points iffy)?

Comment: This is duplicate to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480013/image-processing-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-accuracy/10034214#10034214