# How to make Tesseract recognize o as o and not as zero?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I have following images:

`img01.png`

[image: img01.png]

`img02.png`

[image: img02.png]

When I run `tesseract img01.png img01.txt -l eng --psm 7` I get the texts

- `7.819 0` for the first image and
- `10.024` for the second one.

The second result is correct. However, in the first image, it is an `o` and not a zero.

How can I make Tesseract recognize o as o?

**Update 1:** I tried using the `--oem 1` option as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759527/399457) (`tesseract --oem 1 img01.png img01-ocred -l eng --psm 7`), but it did not help.

**Update 2:** Binarizing the image using `magick img01.png +dither -colors 3 -colors 2 -colorspace gray -normalize img01-binarized.png` also didn't help. the binarized image looks like this:

[image: img01-binarized.png]

Comment: How would a human do that ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust In `img01.png` the `o` is smaller than `0`.

Comment: Then ask Tesseract the size of the characters and adjust yourself.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to enlarge the image twice the original then use tesseract.

```
wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSO87.png

identify -format "%wx%h" bSO87.png 
40x20

tesseract -l eng --oem 3 --psm 6 bSO87.png stdout
7.819 0

convert bSO87.png -resize 80x40 bSO87.png

identify -format "%wx%h" bSO87.png 
80x40

tesseract -l eng --oem 3 --psm 6 bSO87.png stdout
7.819 o
```