# How to recognize deformed text under some other bigger object by using pytesseract and opencv-python in python?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, opencv, python

I am using pytesseract to recognize text as follow

```py
td = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
tn_boxes = len(td['level'])
for o in range(0, tn_boxes):
    text = td['text'][o]
    print(text)
```

i am just making an index of `Examples` by using a simple logic `detect keyword 'Example no.' find it's end point keyword 'Sol.' and put a piece of image from keyword 'Example no.' to keyword 'Sol.' into index and then find next example and so on` 
But when i try following image 
[image: image without line above it]
Then it show output 
`SET THEORY ae . . 5 (6) Let A = {x: x isa negative odd integer} = {-1,-3,-5,-7,`...etc
See how it is not recognizing first line `Sol. (a) Let A={x:x is a natural number`..etc.
And  when i try it with following image not having horizontal line 
[image: image without line above it]
it just works fine.

### Is there any way to configure pytesseract to recognize text with having a line above it ?

#### Edited:

sometimes when we place some image above text or some other text with higher size then pytesseract fails to detect text below that bigger object.

### Is there any solution for this kind of problem may be there is a way to configure detection minimum size or configure to detect all possible sized text even under some bigger objects ?

For example 
it show output `usually denoted by o(G).                        ors a a {= 7 Wave =e () oe that the set of ae |  group usual ition of integers.`
See how it is not detecting keyword `Example 1.`
for folowing image 
[image]

But when i try following image 
it shows output `usually denoted by o(G).    Example 1. (2) Prove that    th .  group under usual addition of integers,`
Now it is detecting keyword `Example 1.`
[image]

Comment: what about removing automatically the black line ? you can easily detect it based and its size (almost the whole width) and position (just above the Sol. text) You can even use it to undistort the text, but that's another topic ;-)

Comment: Thanku for a solution i will try this. But sometimes when we place some image above text or some other text with higher size then pytesseract fails to detect text below that bigger object. Can you suggest any solution for this kind of problem may be there is a way to configure detection minimum size or configure to detect all possible sized text even under some bigger objects

Comment: i submitted a issue https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/3011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read e.g. [image processing to improve tesseract OCR accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480013/image-processing-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-accuracy/10034214#10034214) and read the [docs](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/ImproveQuality.md).

Comment: I found a better dewrapper is [ocrd_cis](https://github.com/cisocrgroup/ocrd_cis)
but for now i don't know how to use it
And When we scale up given image to a scale actor 3 then it detects keyword `Example 1.`

But now question is how to find that scale factor to get best results 
i asked that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480172/tesseract-ocr-act-weird-while-scalling-up-image-size-how-to-know-which-scale-fa)

Comment: i want best results what should i try ? is there any way to configure minimun and maximum font size ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [dewarping](https://mzucker.github.io/2016/08/15/page-dewarping.html) the image. I used this repo 
[dewarp-github](https://github.com/mzucker/page_dewarp)
The code is written in version 2 of python. If you are using version 3+ of python, you can convert this code into version 3 using 
[2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html). It needed some modifications for my case which were not too complex to handle.

Comment: There's a python 3 fork: https://github.com/bertsky/page_dewarp/tree/support-python3