# Tesseract ocr act weird while scalling up image size. How to know which scale factor is best for some particular types of image?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have this
[006.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrbmF.jpg) image and
i tried following python code 
I downloaded "eng" from [tessdata_best](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best) and renamed it to "eng_best"

```py
img = cv2.imread(file_path)
lang = "eng_best"
for img_scale_factor in range (1,8):
    print(file_path, img_scale_factor)
    img = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=img_scale_factor,fy=img_scale_factor)
    hocr_data = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(img, extension="hocr", lang=lang, config="--dpi 1")
    file_name = '{0:03d}_jpg_{1}_x{3}.{2}'.format(6, lang, "hocr", img_scale_factor)
    with open(os.path.join(savediv, file_name), 'w+b') as f:
        f.write(hocr_data)
    print("    Output - {}".format(file_name))
```

I tried above code with varying `img_scale_factor` from `1` upto to `7` which scale given image by that scale factor
Here are output files :
[006_jpg_eng_best_x1.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrWP8.png)
[006_jpg_eng_best_x2.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3VcO.png)
[006_jpg_eng_best_x3.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCeOP.png)
[006_jpg_eng_best_x4.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ7Q3.png)
[006_jpg_eng_best_x5.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jHkq.png)
[006_jpg_eng_best_x6.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiaup.png)
[006_jpg_eng_best_x7.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc8wb.png)

We can clearly observe that Output

1. From `img_scale_factor` `1 to 2` - Increases ocr result.
2. For `img_scale_factor` `3` - best ocr result among all.
3. From `img_scale_factor` `4 to 7` - Decreases ocr result.

For that particular image `img_scale_factor` `3` gives best results.

#### How can we figure out which scale factor is best without checking ocr for every scale factor for some particular types of image ?

May be this can be solved by fixing minimun and maximum font size.
Is there any way to configure minimun and maximum font size ?

**Edit:**
As mentioned at this [FAQ](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ-Old.html#is-there-a-minimum--maximum-text-size-it-wont-read-screen-text)
they recommend the text height of a lower case "x" should be between 10 and 30 px.
I calculated the x-height for scale_factors, for 1 it is 25px, for 2 it is 50px, for 3 it is 75px and so on. in this case it shows more accurate results when x-height is 75px.

Comment: On Tesseract [FAQ](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ-Old.html#is-there-a-minimum--maximum-text-size-it-wont-read-screen-text) they recommend the text height of a lower case "x" should be between 10 and 30 px

Comment: i calculated the x-height for scale_factors, for 1 it is 25px, for 2 it is 50px, for 3 it is 75px and so on. in this case it shows more accurate results when x-height is 75px.