# Pre-process methods to apply before extracting texts from images in distorted,blurred images using pytesseract/tesseract

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am writing a script to extract text from the images of questions like the one given below using `tesseract`. But I am talking about 1000-10000 images per day so manualy applying the methods won't be feasible. Is it possible that I can apply some general things to all the images?

**This image is here to show the quality of images not that it is handwritten**.

[image]

So this image is having some noise, blur and all. I have used `otsu thresholding` and `closing` already. What other methods should be there for pre-processing functions that I can use on each image **safely so that it does not hurt good quality images but improves bad quality**.

In other terms, can I use a `sharpening kernel` to every image?  If yes, What should be average  (minimal safe )filter size/value so that it does not hurt the good quality images

```
sharpen_kernel_choice1 = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen_kernel_choise2 = np.array[[0,-1,0], [-1,9,-1], [0,-1,0]]
```

I am also thinking about using `Wiener Filter` so that it can de-blur the image for example,

```
psf = np.ones((5, 5)) / 25 # what should be a safe kernel size
img = convolve2d(img, psf, 'same')
img += 0.1 * img.std() * np.random.standard_normal(img.shape) # what should be this value?
deconvolved_img = restoration.unsupervised_wiener(img, psf)
```

Comment: you can try Adaptive histogram equalization (CLAHE) before thresholding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [image processing to improve tesseract OCR accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480013/image-processing-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-accuracy)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [edge preserving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge-preserving_smoothing) filters like anisotropic diffusion. The only implementation in python I know of can be found in [medpy](http://loli.github.io/medpy/generated/medpy.filter.smoothing.anisotropic_diffusion.html).

```py
medpy.filter.smoothing.anisotropic_diffusion(gray_image, option = 3)
```

I tried your image and found unsharp masking works even better due to the edge augmenting. And for exposure modification you should defenitely use a local filter, CLAHE as mentioned by Ziri is the best and easiest to use that I can think of.

```py
from skimage.exposure import equalize_adapthist
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu, unsharp_mask

img = unsharp_mask(image)
equalize_adapthist(img) > threshold_otsu(equalize_adapthist(img))
```

The Tesseract project also provides a page dedicated to [Image Preprocessing](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the real problem is that  I want to know if there is a generalised approach. IF only I had to extract from say 10 images per day, I would have manually tweaked the images but I am looking at around 1000-10000 images per day. So is there a generalised approach for that?

Comment: Yes there are a few tutorials, that basically go through the steps that are mentioned on the image preprocessing page of Tesseract. That's what you would usually do. But I am not sure to which extent Tesseract does them itself. If your data is connected to a specific topic it would also be beneficial to train a network for this problem. Also `tesserocr` seems to be a more up to date python wrapper for Tesseract. And last but not least there exist an open source project for handwritten math expressions: https://github.com/falvaro/seshat

Comment: I think these will not work for me in the case. I think either a De Noising GAN or Auto Encoder I should use so that I can get the best of ML. This is just one of the types of images that I have. Almost every image is different so I need to train on around 2-3Lkhs images for Autoencoder I think.

Comment: Now that you're mentioning it I just stumbled upon a tool for denoising and super resolution, maybe that will be worth taking a look. It also worked quite well for making almost not readable letters easily readable, maybe it will also work for hand written letters. https://github.com/tamarott/SinGAN

Comment: thanks bud! Will do that , I think. Been advised about the GAN part by a few people.