# How to change pixel colours in an image using numpy

Tags: image, numpy

I have an image that is converted to a numpy array

```
np_image = np.array(Image.open(filename))
```

I am attempting OCR using *pytesseract*, but the ocr fails when the text is red or yellow and so I want all text to be black.

I am breaking down the image into snippets as I know where the individual text elements appear

As you can see from the code below, I have attempted to find coloured pixels and and convert them to black, but it does not work

```
snippet = np_image[top: bottom, field.left: field.right].copy()
for row in snippet:
    for pixel in row:
        test = [rgb for rgb in pixel[:-1]]
        test.sort()
        if test[0] > 190 and test[2] < 100:
            pixel = [0, 0, 0, 255]

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(snippet)
```

What should I do?

Comment: `test.sort` should do nothing, the `()` are missing

Comment: @JérômeRichard ta. Still doesn't fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pixel = [0, 0, 0, 255]` does not write in the actual image. It just set the value `[0, 0, 0, 255]` to the local variable `pixel`. Assuming `np_image` is a Numpy array, you certainly need to write `pixel[:] = [0, 0, 0, 255]` so that `np_image` can be modified.

Moreover, the `sort` function sorts the values in an increasing order. Thus, the condition seems suspiciously wrong. Indeed, `test[0] <= test[2]` must always be true. Thus, if `test[0] > 190` is true, then `test[2] < 100` cannot be true. As a result, the condition should never be true.

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer to a similar question, I now realise that this is the WRONG approach to improving accuracy in pytesseract OCR. [See this SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480013/image-processing-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-accuracy)