# JavaFX: ScaleTransition, Scale down

Tags: java, animation, javafx

How do I scale **down** an image using ScaleTransition? I have this right now and it only scales **up**. I not if I'm misunderstanding the method, but I have it scaling **From 1** to 0.8. For some reason this still scales up.

```
ScaleTransition st = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(900), iv2);
        st.setFromX(1);
        st.setFromY(1);
        st.setByX(0.8);
        st.setByY(0.8);
        st.play();
```

If I reverse the values like so, it shows up small but snaps bigger and scales up again.

```
ScaleTransition st = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(900), iv2);
        st.setFromX(0.8);
        st.setFromY(0.8);
        st.setByX(1);
        st.setByY(1);
        st.play();
```

Is there a way I can just get the ScaleTransition to scale down?

Comment: Try to use third party library like [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html) and see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497853/scale-a-bufferedimage-the-fastest-and-easiest-way) for more information

Comment: Two things you can try.  I believe either one will work but I can't test them right now.  Either (1) Pass a negative value to `setByX` and `setByY`.  Or (2) Instead of `setByX` and `setByY`, use `setToX` and `setToY`.

Comment: Do you mean an Image in an ImageView? If so, javafx doesnt have a that user friendly sizing/scaling mechansim. Which means its propably the best to search for a thirdparty library for this.

Comment: If you use `setByX(0.8)` that means you scale up by a factor of `1+0.8=1.8`

Comment: Negative values seems to do the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ScaleTransition st = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(900), iv2);
        st.setFromX(1);
        st.setFromY(1);
        st.setToX(0.8);
        st.setToY(0.8);
        st.play();
```

This can scale down, the size of component scale from 100% down to 80%, you can scale up with this code, change 0.8 to a number bigger than 1, sorry my English so bad